# Let $P \in{\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and suppose $P$ is metacyclic. Suppose $(|G|, p^2 - 1) = 1$. Show that $G$ has a normal $p$ complement.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $P \in{\rm Syl}_p(G)$ and suppose $P$ is metacyclic. Suppose $(|G|, p^2 - 1) = 1$. Show that $G$ has a normal $p$ complement.

Since $P$ is metacycilc, let $N \unlhd P$ so that $P/N$ is cyclic. Let $m, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $|P| = p^m$, and $|N| = p^k$ First we will show $N_{G/N}(P/N) = C_{G/N}(P/N)$. We know  $$|N_{G/N}(P/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| \, / \, |\textbf{Aut}(P/N)| = \phi(p^{m - k}) = (p - 1)p^{m - k - 1}. $$
But $|$Aut$(P/N)| \, / \, |G|$, and $(|G|, (p - 1)(p + 1)) = (|G|, p^2 - 1) = 1$. So $$(|\textbf{Aut}(P/N)|, p - 1)  = 1.$$
Therefore $$|N_{G/N}(P/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| \, / \, p^{m - k - 1}.$$
Now
$$|N_{G/N}(P/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| \, / \, |(G/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| \, / \, |(G/N)/(P/N)|$$ , but since $(|G/N|, p) = 1$, we have
$$(|N_{G/N}(P/N)/N_{G/N}(P/N)|, p) = 1.$$
Therefore $|N_{G/N}(P/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| = 1$, hence $N_{G/N}(P/N) = C_{G/N}(P/N)$.
\newline
\newline
Now $N_{N_G(N)/N}(P/N) =  (N_G(P)/N) \cap N_{G/N}(P/N)=  (N_G(N)/N) \cap C_{G/N}(P/N)$
\newline
$= C_{N_G(N)/N}(P/N)$. So  by the correspondence theorem,
$$N_{N_G}(N)(P) = C_{N_G}(N)(P)$$

Now
$$|N_{G/N}(P/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| \, / \, |(G/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| \, / \, |(G/N)/(P/N)|$$ , but since $(|G/N|, p) = 1$, we have
$$(|N_{G/N}(P/N)/N_{G/N}(P/N)|, p) = 1.$$
Therefore $|N_{G/N}(P/N)/C_{G/N}(P/N)| = 1$, hence $N_{G/N}(P/N) = C_{G/N}(P/N)$.

***My problem is I want to some how use $N_{G/N}(P/N) = C_{G/N}(P/N)$ to get $N_G(P) = C_G(P)$, but can't just use the correspondence theorem, since $N$ might not be normal in $G$

I can show $N_{N_G(N)/N}(P/N) =  (N_G(P)/N) \cap N_{G/N}(P/N)=  (N_G(N)/N) \cap C_{G/N}(P/N)$
$= C_{N_G(N)/N}(P/N)$. So  by the correspondence theorem,
$$N_{N_G(N)}(P) = C_{N_G(N)}(P)$$
and get $N_G(N)$ has a normal $p$ complement.

I feel like I'm some how supposed to use $p \in{\rm Syl}_p(G)$ or $P/N$ is cyclic, but not sure how?

***Edit: Looking at Frobenius's normal p-complement.

If $N \leq A \leq P$, then I can show $N_G(A)$ has a normal $p$-compliment, similarly to how I originally showed $N_G(N)$ has a normal p-complement, since $A  \unlhd P$ and $P/A$  is cyclic. But not sure what to do if $N \nleq A$?

Comment: Do you know that a $p'$-automorphism of a $p$-group acts non-trivially on the quotient by the Frattini subgroup? Frobenius's normal $p$-complement would also come in handy here (although there are other ways).

Comment: I don't know you mean by p'-automorphism? Do you mean the automorphism group, of a commutator subgroup of a p-group?

Comment: $p'$-automorphism = automorphism of order prime to $p$. Like $p'$-group.

Comment: How did this problem arise?

Comment: I literally just defined what a $p'$-automorphism was. It is an automorphism whose order is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: Trying to read a book about finite group theory by Martin Issacc's.

Comment: I think I may have miss understood some of this notation, and thought he was referencing the commutator of p-groups in some theorems.

Comment: Ah. If $\pi$ is a set of primes then $\pi'$ is all primes not in $\pi$. If $\pi=\{p\}$ then we write $p'=\{p\}'$. This is different from $G'$, which is standard notation for the commutator subgroup (and also not for many authors, unfortunately). In your case, use Theorem 5.26 from Isaacs's book.

Comment: Since $|$Aut$(P/N)| = (p-1)p^{m - k -1}$, I'm assuming I should be looking at an automorphism of order $p - 1$?

Comment: Was I completely off track by proving $N_{G/N}(P/N) = C_{G/N}(P/N)$?

Comment: Looking at Frobenius's normal p-complement. I can get That for any p-subgroup $H/N$ of $G/N$, that $N_{G/N}(H/N)/C_{G/N}(H/N)$ is a p-group, so by  Frobenius's normal p-complement, G/N has a normal p-complement.

Comment: If $N \leq A \leq P$, then I can show $N_G(A)$ has a normal $p$-compliment, similarly to how I originally showed $N_G(N)$ has a normal p-complement, since $A  \unlhd P$ and $P/A$  is cyclic. But not sure what to do if $N \nleq A$?